# flutter Ios build fails after upgrading firebase core

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I had a flutter app which was working fine with firebase core (version `0.4.0`). I upgraded the firebase_core to version `0.5.0` and did all changes as per the migration. After that ios build is giving following error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
 
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
Xcode build done.                                           95.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    AssertMacros: amdErr = AMDeviceConnect(tmpDevice) == 0 ,  file:
    /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MobileDevice/MobileDevice-1190.100.2.1/Source/AMDevicePowerAssertion.c, line: 224, value: -402653083
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleUtilities' does not include header 'GULLoggerCodes.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/GoogleUtilities-umbrella.h"
    ^
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/yogesh/projects/mobile-flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:24:
    /Users/yogesh/projects/mobile-flutter/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/GoogleUtilities/Logger/Private/GULLogger.h:22:9: fatal error: could not build module
    'GoogleUtilities'
    #import <GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

It is running fine in android and even building ios build from xcode also works fine. Its build and run from command line which fails (`flutter run`)

Following is my pubspec file containing firebase dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  sqflite:
  path:
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
```

i am not able to understand is it because of library error or something from my side because it seems lib error but android and ios build from xcode works totally fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Run command

> flutter clean

And then re-run the application works for me.

Answer (score 11):

I have just had the same issue as in I was able to run the app from XCode Runner but not from within Android Studio with the same exact error message. I managed to fix the issue via these steps:

1. Adding `firebase_analytics: ^6.0.0` to pubspec.yaml.
2. Then removing `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock`.
3. And finally running it again.

However I cannot tell you why exactly it resolved the issue so cannot really guarantee this will work out for you.

Comment: Yes this worked actually and i am also not able to understand why. Thanks

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work without much manipulations of the iOS folder.

Answer (score 2):

delete **Podfile** and **Podfile.lock** and run it, it will work